# Cache objects and avoid having duplicate objects for database rows

Tags: c++, qt, caching, qt5

I have an application where thousands of rows are loaded from database (up to 250,000) and mapped into objects from the same type (T1).

However this rows have a foreign key for rows in another table which are also loaded on demand and mapped into objects of type T2.

I don't have a cache in place, and objects (so far) can exist simultaneously in my system, even if they represent the same row in the database.

I think this is probably not the best solution. What can I do in order to cache objects and keep the relationships?

To my application is unavoidable to check the database all the time (because of complex filters, etc. that the user can apply during execution) but I think the good thing would be to know, after a query to the database, when a row is already in memory represented by an object and use that same object, instead of creating it again.

I'm interested in solutions, ideas and links to useful resources.

Comment: Perhaps something like :
http://www.qxorm.com/qxorm_en/home.html
or some other ORM

Comment: I was actually thinking in something simpler than an ORM framework? I was checking the class QCache but it seems to take ownership of the elements and I'm using QSharedPointers which I don't think would work with that class.

Comment: You can implement your own classes based on the multiton pattern.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton
This would allow you to manage the cache how ever you liked.

Comment: @WilliamJones sounds interesting, didn't know of the "Multi" version of this pattern. Any clues about implementing it threadsafe with a LRU policy applied when the cache reaches a certain size, etc. with QT?

Comment: Seems like you are looking for something more like an ORM.  I would imagine that by the time you have implemented a thread safe LRU with cache size management you will have implemented 50% of a good ORM.  The rest of the ORM (maybe the part you don't need) is getting and putting the persistence model.  Is there other motivation not to use one?